# Fraction substraction arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic

$$
3\frac38 - \frac56-1\frac23={}?
$$

Can you solve this fraction substraction? I’m getting the wrong answer, on my book the answer is $\frac78$.

Comment: What answer do you get, and how do you get there?

Comment: If you show us what you did then we may be able to help you spot where you went wrong

Comment: 3 3/8=2 3/8+8/8=2 11/8 . mmc =24 , 2 33/24-20/24-1 16/24???

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley your steps are correct so far

Comment: It’s mixed numbers, not multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, expanding the fractions

$\left(3+\frac{3}{8}\right)-\frac{5}{6}-\left(1+\frac{2}{3}\right) = \frac{24+3}{8}-\frac{5}{6}-\frac{3+2}{3}=\frac{27}{8}-\frac{5}{6}-\frac{5}{3}$

Next, finding a common quotient and subtracting

$\frac{27}{8}-\frac{5}{6}-\frac{5}{3} = \frac{(27\times 6 \times 3)-(5\times 8 \times 3)-(5\times 8 \times 6)}{8\times6\times3}=\frac{486-120-240}{144}=\frac{126}{144}=\frac{7\times(18)}{8\times(18)}=\frac{7}{8}$

The answer is $\boxed{\frac{7}{8}}$

Comment: I think $3\frac38$ means $3+\frac38$ not $3\times\frac38$.

Comment: It is common, at the level someone would ask this question, that 

$$3 \, \frac 3 8$$

is a mixed fraction, "3 and 3 eighths", not "$3 \cdot 3/8$" ($3$ times $3/8$), i.e.

$$3 \, \frac 3 8 = 3 + \frac 3 8$$

Comment: Makes sense! tks for observing

Comment: Ok! But on my books answer key is 7/8

Comment: Did the corrections pointed on comments.

Comment: I used the mmc :24 ,and got 21/24 and reduced to 7/8.Why do you multiply those numbers like (27x6x3)?